# i want to retain post value after form submission in my code please help(in the input box name quantity )

Tags: php

```
require_once "db/database.php";
$db = new Database();
$db->connect(); 
foreach($_POST['add_to_cart'] as $id)
 {
 $select_datas = "SELECT * FROM sub_category where sub_category_id = $id";
 $display_datas = $db->executeStatement($select_datas);
 $get_sub_category_data_results=mysqli_fetch_assoc($display_datas); 
 $sub_category_name= $get_sub_category_data_results['sub_category_name'];
 $model_no= $get_sub_category_data_results['model_no'];
 $amount= $get_sub_category_data_results['amount'];

$result .= '<tr>';?>
<?php $result .= '<td> '.$sub_category_name.' </td>';?> 
<?php $result .= '<td> '.$model_no.'   </td>';?>
<?php $result .= '<td> '.$amount.'   </td>';?>
<?php $result .= '<td>' .'<input type="text"  value="'.(isset($_POST['quantity']) ?     $_POST['quantity'] : '').' "   name="quantity" />'.'</td></tr>';?>
<?php
 }
$result .= '</table>';
echo $result;
```

I want to retain post data after form submit. if I use `echo` in front of `(isset($_POST['quantity']) ?     $_POST['quantity'] : '')` it shows `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in..`

Comment: Is the problem the echo or retaining the post values?

Comment: Any reason why you're opening and closing PHP tags on each line?

Comment: sory i forget     $result .= '<tr>';
$result .= '<td> '.$sub_category_name.' </td>';
$result .= '<td> '.$model_no.'   </td>';
$result .= '<td> '.$amount.'   </td>';
$result .= '<td>' .'<input type="text"  value="'.echo(isset($_POST['quantity']) ? $_POST['quantity'] : '').' "   name="quantity" />'.'</td></tr>';

Comment: just now i saw that code.  i removed opening and closing PHP tags on each line

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity']) ? $_POST['quantity'] : ''; ?>
<?php $result .= '<td>' .'<input type="text"  value="'. $quantity .' "   name="quantity" />'.'</td></tr>';?>
```

The above should work.

Comment: sory sir still not working

Comment: i want retain value after postback if i use echo in value tag error shows?...

Answer (score 0):

The echo is not needed because you are already telling it to append the result of the if statement to the variable $result by using the `.` to combine them.

For saving the `$result` value, you just need to echo the value as the value of the input of the form that you are sending:

```
<input type='hidden' name='result' value='<?php echo $result?>'>
```

In addition, this line:

```
<?php $result .= '<td>' .'<input type="text"  value="'.(isset($_POST['quantity']) ?     $_POST['quantity'] : '').' "   name="quantity" />'.'</td></tr>';?>
```

Should be changed to this:

```
<?php $result .= '<td>' .'<input type="text"  value="'.((isset($_POST['quantity'])) ?     $_POST['quantity'] : '').' "   name="quantity" />'.'</td></tr>';?>
```

The entire if statement needs to be in quotes for it to work properly.

Comment: i want to send the values to email. So i concatenate all the table values to result variable. once value stored to result variable i need to send the variable to email id

Comment: Ok.  You do not need the echo in order to combine them all into the result variable and there are numerous guides for mailing using PHP.

Comment: i want retain the $result variable value after postback

Comment: Ok.  See the second part of the updated answer.

Comment: i m using foreach loop for storing database values into variable result along with quantity input from user. once user enter submit all the values are stored result variable. but my issue is input value is not stored in the varible result..got it?

Comment: all the values shown but quantity value not showing same problem????

Comment: Now I understand and the solution should work now.

Comment: error shown Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: bcoz one you didnt closed open bracket properly

Comment: if i add properly even though value not retain???

Comment: My mistake but it should work after that.

Comment: can you help how to retain quantity text value after postback please correct my code???

Comment: Yes, use the edited code I just put: `<?php $result .= '<td>' .'<input type="text"  value="'.((isset($_POST['quantity'])) ?     $_POST['quantity'] : '').' "   name="quantity" />'.'</td></tr>';?>`

Comment: alternative way to retain???

Comment: The code I gave is tested and works.  Make sure that you are actually testing it when `$_POST['quantity']` is set.

Comment: ya i set $_POST['quantity'] this only wait i will all my code once again

Comment: $result .= '<tr>';
$result .= '<td> '.$sub_category_name.' </td>';
$result .= '<td> '.$model_no.'   </td>';
$result .= '<td> '.$amount.'   </td>';
$result .= '<td>' .'<input type="text" value="'.((isset($_POST['quantity'])) ? $_POST['quantity'] : '').' " name="quantity" />'.'</td></tr>';

Comment: Then you're either not echoing result or there is an error somewhere in your code.

Comment: no error but i value not retain retain. can you help how to receive the data after form submission?

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$result_var   = trim($_POST['result']);
echo $result_var;} this is right?

Comment: `$result_var` is not the same as `$result`.

Comment: ya i know i just received form variables and stored into $result_var

Comment: in ur side the code are working????

Comment: I'm very confused.  If you want to send `$result` through a post variable, use `<input type='hidden' name='result' value='<?php echo $result?>'>` in order to send `$_POST['result'].  I don't see any reason that the code I provided would not work though unless `$_POST['quantity']` is not set, there is an error with the code, or you do not echo it correctly in order to check.

Comment: just i want retain the text box value in the foreach loop ok. dynamically quantity text box should be generate. so i submit all the text box quantity values are stored to be result variable and finaly i want to send the variable to email id. but my issue is textbox value not appered which i was entered ??got it..

Comment: The only thing I can see possibly wrong in your code is that you don't have a form.

Comment: http://halcyona.in/our_works.php?sub_cat_name=COT/BED

Comment: then select products and proceed booking

Comment: The name of your submit button is `check_cart`, but you check `$_POST['submit']`.  Is this right?

Comment: check_cart is coming from previous page current page my submit button name is submit only so that is rigth

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to go through every aspect of your website looking for errors.  You will need to do some debugging.  Everything in my answer is tested and should be working exactly as it should.